# Filtering 2 tables from one field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to filter 2 different tables from 1 search/filter input
Now, this code below is working on filtering one table that has the `table1` ID
`#searchInput` is the ID of the text field I'm using

```
  $("#searchInput").keyup(function () {
    //split the current value of searchInput
    var data = this.value.split(" ");
    //create a jquery object of the rows
    var jo = $("#table1").find("tr");
    if (this.value == "") {
        jo.show();
        return;
    }
    //hide all the rows
    jo.hide();

    //Recusively filter the jquery object to get results.
    jo.filter(function (i, v) {
        var $t = $(this);
        for (var d = 0; d < data.length; ++d) {
            if ($t.is(":contains('" + data[d] + "')")) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    })
    //show the rows that match.
    .show();

 }).focus(function () {
    this.value = "";
    $(this).css({
        "color": "black"
    });
    $(this).unbind('focus');

 }).css({ "color": "#C0C0C0"});
```

I tried:`<br />`

```
 $("#table1, #table2").find("tr");<br/>
```

and:`<br />`

```
 $("#table1", "table2").find("tr");<br />
```

but none of them would work!

Comment: Your `.find()` calls could return multiple results but you treat the result as if it is returning a single one: `jo.show()`.

Comment: @SquareCat so how do I do that o.O ?

Comment: Like this: `$("#table1").find("tr").each(function(){ this.show(); });`

Comment: @SquareCat unfortunately this is not working for some reason...
Were you saying to do this: http://pastebin.com/yaep2gad

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle.net. Much easier to help when people can test code

Comment: @charlietfl http://jsfiddle.net/Eybwj/ Note: I put the code at hte HTML part since that needs to be run last, and I'm not very familiar with jsfiddle...

Comment: I made a minor adjustment of selectors for `jo` and seems to work...http://jsfiddle.net/Eybwj/1/

Comment: Yes using class selector fixed the problem. But why do you spilt the serach string? i have updated the fiddle by Mr. charlietfl to match the string user types. http://jsfiddle.net/Eybwj/2/